# Does Elemental Affinity add damage to Witch Bolt only once?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, sorcerer

If a 6th level Sorcerer with Elemental Affinity (lightning) casts Witch Bolt, is only the inital bolt's damage is increased, or the damage of every one of them?

**Elemental Affinity:**

> [...] when you cast a spell that deals damage of the type associated with your draconic ancestry, add your Charisma modifier to that damage.

**Witch Bolt:**

> [...]  on each of your turns for the duration, you can use your action to deal 1d12 lightning damage to the target automatically.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Only Once

Elemental Affinity adds damage "when you cast a spell..."

The damage of *witch bolt* that can be applied on subsequent turns is not "casting a spell" but instead taking a special action granted to you by the *witch bolt* spell. Since you're not casting a spell, the additional damage from Elemental Affinity will not apply.

Answer (score 8):

## Yes, only to when you first cast the spell.

Per [The Player's Handbook Errata](https://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/PH-Errata-V1.pdf),

> **Elemental Affinity (p. 102).** The damage bonus applies to one damage roll of a spell, not multiple rolls.

## Old Answer

Since you're not casting a spell to automatically deal the damage, Elemental Affinity only applies for the initial damage.